# Where to store api keys in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, key

I'm currently working with Flutter web with a PHP backend that is protected with an API Key.
Where should I store the API Key in Flutter Web? The package "flutter_secure_storage" is not available for web so it is not an option.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is your API Key unique to every client? Are the requests to the backend being validated / is the API key public?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **SharedPreferences** plugin for storing and retrieving persistent simple data. They supported for the web from version 0.5.4+7

Comment: is it save to use? Where should I assign the value?

Comment: shared_preferences: '>=0.5.y+x <2.0.0'                                                
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();                                 prefs.put('counter',1);
  int counter = prefs.getInt('counter');

Comment: the [shared_preferences page on pub.get](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) lists the storage mechanism for web as "LocalStorage". Anyone who can open inspect element could see your API keys if you store them this way. I don't think there is any good way to store secrets on the client side of a webapp in a secure way.